# Delete specific pattern in a word from a Text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following lines in my file:

```
demo-ns,demoapp-v1-v000,2733202e0e44c0c8f49a220e5596113ee35e2566
demo-ns,demoapp-v2-v001,3b3f0592b933add32f10b7e1a7535837009a4c64
```

I want to remove the characters `-v000` and `-v001`. The pattern is `v[0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

I am expecting the following output:

```
demo-ns,demoapp-v1,2733202e0e44c0c8f49a220e5596113ee35e2566
demo-ns,demoapp-v2,3b3f0592b933add32f10b7e1a7535837009a4c64
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed -e 's/-v[0-9][0-9][0-9],/,/'`

The added comma provides a little bit of context to guard against replacing too aggressively.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/-v[0-9]{3}//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="," } { sub(/-v[0-9]*$/,"",$2); print }' file
```

Set the input field separator `FS` and output field separator `OFS` to a comma.
Then substitute regex pattern `-v[0-9]*$` on the second comma separated field `$2` with an empty string and print the line.